# daterangepicker Month and year hard to view

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following daterangepicker code. the code is functioning however the Month, Year and toggle buttons are very hard to view. I am using a bootstrap theme that is not working well with this. I have been trying to figure out how to change the CSS to make the month, year and toggle buttons more viewable.

**What I am seeing**
[image]

**This is what it should look like**
[image]

```
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />


<form class="" action="{{ url_for('about') }}" name="Item_1" method="POST">
    <input style="width: 30%" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 01/31/2015" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

    </form>



<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
{
    locale: {
      format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
    },
    startDate: '01-01-2017',
    endDate: moment()
}, 
function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date range was chosen: " + start.format('MM-DD-YYYY') + ' to ' + end.format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you do something like `.calendar-table, .glyphicon-calendar {color: #000 !important;}`, does that clear it up? If so, it looks like it's just the `color` attribute of those elements, but I would suggest using dev tools to figure out what existing CSS rule is changing them to a lighter color and change that lighter color to black, instead of using `!important`. From your code sample, it doesn't appear anything there is changing it to a lighter color - do you have inline CSS in that same file, or pull another stylesheet?

Comment: This actually dose work. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking it here as an answer, since the comment worked. The `color` css attribute controls font-colors, including those for glyphicons. So the fix is to change the corresponding table elements and glyphicons to use `color: #000` or `color: black`.

Adding `!important` simply ensures no other CSS files change the color (unless they use `!important` too and have priority, through either more specific selectors, or the same selectors but appearing after this rule - which was apparently not the case here).

```
.calendar-table, .glyphicon-calendar {color: #000 !important;}
```